# AutoIncrement and DataRelation in a c# typed dataset (from mysql)

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, data-binding

I am trying to set up a DataRelation between two mysql Tables. The parent-table "organisations" has a primary-key (int, autoinc) named “organisationID”.

The child table (“authors”) stores the foreignkey (organisations.organisationID) as “organisation” (int).

Now when I try to setup the DataRelation I will always get an exception: Parent Columns and Child Columns don't have type-matching columns.

My guess is that .NET is sensing a type difference between the autoinc int and the regular int of the foreignkey column.

Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to set your foreign key to type INT in your dataset designer

Comment: you are right, I had uint (both places), why on earth does not work with uint is beyond me